# Need to decide which way take to develop an Android App

Tags: android

I'm currently getting involved in an app project with a web site that will mirror its actions, the main goal is to confirm presence in clubs and bars and get discounts with it. (A little more than that, but not the scope of the question).

Despite my programming experience, I've never developed an app before, and at this time we already have the front-end of the website done, my question is if there is any advantage in developing the app from scratch, with an IDE or is it just time-wasting compared to using tools like those recommended in this article [here](http://mashable.com/2013/12/03/build-mobile-apps/).

What could be the drawbacks of just "converting" the website to an app?

**TL;DR: Developing an app, is worth it to develop with an IDE or an online paid tool should do this job perfectly?**

Comment: Both the options are viable. Facebook, an extremely popular app just uses a WebView and renders the mobile version of their website (I am oversimplifying here). You still need a mobile version of the website though. The downside is, it will not look (or feel) as good as a native app. On the other hand, a separate native app means more maintenance efforts. Pick your poison.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I think I'm going to follow the native-path, even though its a harder way of doing this, I can learn much more with it.

Comment: I have moved the comment to an answer. Please accept if it is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the options are viable.

*Facebook*, an extremely popular app just uses a `WebView` and renders the mobile version of their website (I am oversimplifying here). You still need a mobile version of the website though. The downside is, it will not look (or feel) as good as a native app.

On the other hand, a separate native app means more maintenance efforts.

Pick your poison.